# Docker build is failing at step RUN mvn package -DskipTests

Tags: docker, maven, fly

My docker build which was working totally fine before is now failing at below step of docker.

```
RUN mvn package -DskipTests
```

Getting error:

> failed to fetch an image or build from source: error building: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mvn package -DskipTests]: exit code: 1

Here is my whole docker file.

```
# Using a base image with JDK 11 and Gradle  
FROM maven:3.8.6-openjdk-11 AS build

# set as working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy files from your project to the working directory
COPY . /app

# Run Gradle to build the project
RUN mvn package -DskipTests

# Create a new image based on OpenJDK 11
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim-buster

# Expose the port that the application will use 
EXPOSE 8080

# Copy the JAR file built from the previous step
COPY --from=build /app/target/kaim-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/kaim-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

# Set the entry point to run the application 
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=prod", "-jar", "/app/kaim-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Earlier it was working fine; but just out of nowhere, I got this issue, and now deployments are stuck.

I am using `flyctl` for deploying my Docker build and running my application.

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting but I had to guess heavily which backslashes and asterisks were part of the actual `Dockerfile` and which ones were your attempt to format it. Please review; and, going forward, please use code formatting for code. On the desktop version of this site, paste your code, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K to correctly format your code with indentations etc preserved.

Comment: The error message indicates that your `mvn` invocation is failing. The simplest possible explanation is that you changed something which you thought was insignificant. Probably remove Docker from the picture entirely and post a different question about your Maven problem (and probably delete this); or, [edit] the question to show us how any other command in the Docker image also fails similarly if you really can prove that this is a Docker issue (but even then, we will probably need more background information to be able to reproduce the problem).

Comment: See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: @tripleee this is the whole issue am getting .------
Error: failed to fetch an image or build from source: error building: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c mvn clean install -DskipTests]: exit code: 1

Comment: So then the problem is apparently that `FROM maven:3.8.6-openjdk-11 AS build` isn't vald, or you have something blocking network connections to Docker Hub. Can you `docker run` this image?